# XtraReport  side by side  Export problem on excel

Tags: c#, reporting, devexpress, xtrareport

Work on **vs2008 C#** .I has a **side by side report**, On this report, I Face some peculiar problem **attach picture** describe in detail about the property of my XtraReport report **detail bands**.I use **Multicolumn->Direction -> property -> AcrossThenDown** then export in pdf works fine, but problem arise when I export in excel,doc or other format.But I need to export in excel and doc format.Can anybody tell me why I face this problem. How can I retrieve this problem?

```
DownThenAcross--->problem occurs right side report missing.
AcrossThenDown--->I get the multicolumn report but problem on export in doc,excel.
```

if have any query plz ask.Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears because export to xls and doc are not page based as export to PDF.  The solution to this problem is to set the report's ExportOptions.Rtf(Xlsx).ExportMode property to DevExpress.XtraPrinting.XlsxExportMode.SingleFilePageByPage value.

Comment: thanks for reply.I don't understand your given information.will you plz describe how to use ExportOptions.Rtf(Xlsx).ExportMode .Where to use ,in C# code or XtraReport.

Comment: You should set the report's ExportOptions.Rtf.ExportMode and ExportOptions.Xlsx.ExportMode properties.  ExportOptions (http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReport_ExportOptionstopic) is the  property of the XtraReport class and they can be changed even in design time.

Comment: those properties are already  set on report.above I add a picture contains the report report property.This not effect the export ,Problem remains.Thanks for reply